# How to get the Message Id from a Spring Listener

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-jms

I have the following code:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "myQueue", containerFactory = "myFactory")
public void receiveMessage(MyClass message) {
    service.process(message);
}
```

Now, I want to obtain the jms message id. I know I can override the `MappingJackson2MessageConverter`  class to do this, but is it possible to do it in a simpler way, like with a second argument on the method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `@Header` annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So46794317Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So46794317Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(JmsTemplate template) {
        return args -> template.convertAndSend("foo", "bar");
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "foo")
    public void receive(String in, @Header(JmsHeaders.MESSAGE_ID) String messageId) {
        System.out.println(in + ", id:" + messageId);
    }

}
```

Result:

```
bar, id:ID:host.local-50513-1508260336349-4:2:1:1:1
```